# apply() function convert int datatype to decimal and way to prevent auto conversion

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I facing the scenario in which I am implementing apply() function in a dataframe but apply function at convert int to decimal

example

```
df
A      B      C
12    2.3    40
Nan   29.0   23
2     NaN    3.4
3.9   3      2
```

when I am implementing apply it will convert int values to decimal.

```
df['A']=df['A'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x!=x else x)
```

```
A       B      C
12.00  2.3     40
0.00   29.0    23
2.00   NaN     3.4
3.90   3       2
```

Expected Dataframe:

```
A       B      C
12  2.3     40
0   29.0    23
2   NaN     3.4
3.9   3       2
```

Final Goal to creates below dataframe:

```
A         B      C
int    decimal  int
int    decimal  int
int    decimal  decimal
decimal  int    int
```

even I tried

```
df['A']=df['A'].apply(lambda x: o if x!=x else int(x))
```

but that will convert decimal values to int.
can anyone suggest to me how to prevent suggest conversion as I am very much concerned regarding the datatype of the cells of dataframe.

Note: I am not using fillna() as it is also causing some issues of auto conversion of int to decimal.

if anyone has an alternate solution to prevent this is also helpfull.

Comment: What do you mean with *issues of auto conversion of int to decimal*? Are you talking about `float`? Isn't you column `A` supposed to be `float` anyway as you have `3.9`?

Comment: what is the `dtype` of whole data frame? is it object ? .. please show the output of `df.dtypes`

Comment: @mozway, I am focusing on the cells of the data frame where this  int converted to decimal after using apply() function on dataframe columns

Comment: Each column of a pandas dataframe is a pandas series, and a series always has one data type based on the values in it, if one the value is floating or `NaN`, entire column will be foat data type.

Comment: I think you mean "float", not [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html). But anyway, what is the underlying reason for not using `fillna`?

Comment: What does `x != x` means?

Comment: @Aryerez , numpy.nan != numpy.nan is always true

Answer (score 0):

use as `astype('O')` for data type conversion as object

```py
df['A']=df['A'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x!=x else x).astype('O')
```

to fill the entire data frame or single column you can use `fillna` method as same way

```
df.fillna(0).astype('O')
```

Comment: this solution also convert every cell values to float / decimal

Comment: Which pandas version are you using?